# Saving file name with special characters (for example: #) and Japanese letters and get gibberish file name

Tags: internet-explorer, utf-8, character-encoding

I am working with Internet Explorer 11.

I am trying to save a file with the name: れは私の新しいプロジェクト名です (Japanese letters).

When the browser suggest me to save the file I get the file name: `ã‚Œã¯ç§ã®æ–°ã—ã„ãƒ—ãƒ­ã‚¸ã‚§ã‚¯ãƒˆåã§ã™.pdf`

I saw in `fiddler` that the name of the file is correct and the content type is `UTF-8.`

It also happens with special characters.

Does anyone have a clue how to solve this problem?

Comment: Give us the details of how exactly you send the filename.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to encode the filename parameter of Content-Disposition header in HTTP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http)

Answer (score 0):

Your browser has the correct bytes of your japanese filename but it shows the utf-8 3-bytes sequences as if they were single characters (you have 16 japanese characters whereby all of them are utf-8 encoded with a 3-byte sequence). Looks like it is just a display problem i assume. When the browser shows you the filename it doesn't decode the bytes as utf-8 but as iso-8859-1!